# Postgresql 13 генерирует логи, хотя в postgresql.conf логирование не включено

Tags: postgresql, логирование

Postgresql 13 генеририрует огромное количество логов в директорию /var/lib/postgresql/13/main/log, хотя в postgresql.conf логирование не включено. Причём логируются просто вообще все запросы к БД. Как-то можно отключить логирование? Debian 11.

**Updated:** Опытным путём было выявлено, что в таблице pg_settings действительно установлены параметры `log_min_duration_statement = 0` и `logging_collector = on`. Но на изменение postgresql.conf параметры в таблице pg_settings никак не реагируют. После изменения postgresql.conf postgresql перезапускал командой systemctl restart postgresql. В файле postgresql.conf параметр `logging_collector = off`.

Comment: Вроде выключение не предусмотрено в postgre, но можно перенаправить их в /dev/null, `logging_collector = off`, `log_destination = 'stderr'`, `log_filename = /dev/null`

Comment: добавьте в ответ `select name, setting from pg_settings where category like 'Reporting and Logging%';`. Логирование каждого запроса - это или log_statement = all или log_min_duration_statement = 0 - оба не являются дефолтными настройками, значит включали специально.

Comment: В таблице pg_settings действительно установлены параметры log_min_duration_statement = 0 и logging_collector = on. Но на изменение postgresql.conf параметры в таблице pg_settings никак не реагируют. После изменения postgresql.conf postgresql перезапускал командой systemctl restart postgresql.

Comment: проверьте по `select distinct sourcefile from pg_settings ;` в одном и том же ли месте вы и база читаете конфигурацию.

Comment: Да, действительно, конфигурация считывается из файла /etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf, тогда как я вносил изменения в файл /var/lib/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf. Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конфигурация считывается из файла /etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf, тогда как изменения вносились в файл /var/lib/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf. После корректировки соответствующего файла проблема была решена.